# JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: java, eclipse, ejb, jboss7.x

This is my client code

```
package com.tutorialspoint.test;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import com.tutorialspoint.stateless.testRemote;

public class test 
{
    BufferedReader brConsoleReader = null;
    Properties props;
    static InitialContext ctx;
    {
        props = new Properties();
        try {
            props.load(new FileInputStream("jndi.properties"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext(props);            
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        brConsoleReader = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    test _test = new test();
    try {
        testRemote libraryBean =(testRemote)ctx.lookup("java:global/TestEjb/testBean!     
           com.tutorialspoint.stateless.testRemote");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
}
}
```

This is deployed on server

```
package com.tutorialspoint.stateless;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
@Stateless
public class testBean implements testRemote 
{
  public void hello()
  {
    System.out.println("hello");
  }
}

 package com.tutorialspoint.stateless;
 import javax.ejb.Remote;

 @Remote
 public interface testRemote 
 {
    void hello();
 }
```

I am getting exception on server side:

> 19:09:12,676 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "cognam-
> pc-26" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed:
> java.io.IOException: An   existing connection was forcibly closed by the
> remote host

I am getting exception on client side:-

> javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection
> to any of these urls: localhost:4447 and discovery failed with error:
> javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception
> is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out]   [Root exception
> is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to retrieve stub from
> server localhost:4447 [Root exception is java.io.StreamCorruptedException:
> invalid stream header: 0000000F]]
>
> org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1414)
> at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:594)
> at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:587)
> at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
> at com.tutorialspoint.test.test.main(test.java:37)

Comment: it's getting called only one time

Comment: Then I guess your cut and paste was incorrect or I read it wrong, I will delete my comments.

Comment: It might be that your server is not actually allowing connections to 4447. Check if you can telnet to that port or use netstat -an to query this.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your server is not actually allowing connections to 4447. Check if you can telnet to that port or use netstat -an to query this.

Also ensure that there is no firewall blocking access to the port.

Comment: thanx for reply,I have done this by changing jndi.proerties,before i        
 was using jnp context   after changing jndi.properties:-                        
 props = new Properties();     props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
               props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447"); 
               props.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
                  props.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");

Comment: Am not following, does that mean your problem is resolved?

Comment: can anyone tell me how can i configure ejb security with credential at the time of ejb calling

Answer (score 0):

Try shutdown any http traffic capture tools if running (e.g. Fiddler)